# stop processing in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to exit a javascript script without tracking back through all called functions with return. Sort of like a *gasp* GOTO.  Or maybe setting an infinite timer that does not take up too much CPU time. I want to use this to stop processing and warn user on unexpected exception/error cases.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no exit function.

Comment: The only way to make JavaScript in a browser stop running is to use an "alert()" or "confirm()" dialog.

Comment: Pointy: after alert() javascript process still continues so how you stop that process ?!

Answer (score 2):

In unexpected or exceptional cases, throw an exception. You still should have a root try/catch block so that it doesn't affect anything else.